# Django user registration form best practices

Tags: python, django

Django way of customizing the user creation is by adding UserProfile model, however when I am performing user registration, I would like the user to fill all the details, including the ones in the user profile as well.

Using forms.ModelForm seems like the easiest way, however I am dealing here with two models.
What is the easiest way to accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

[`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) may come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:
http://uswaretech.com/books/djangodesignpatterns/misc.html#saving-multiple-objects-in-one-form

Comment: This link is gone. :-(

Comment: The target of this link can also be found elsewhere.... http://agiliq.com/books/djangodesignpatterns/forms.html#saving-multiple-objects-in-one-form

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this too: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/